# NSDate Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

How do I create a NSDate of August 1, 2005? Found NSDateComponent on the internet, but seems too complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possibility is to use [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSCalendar`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html). For instance:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:2000];
[comps setMonth:1];
[comps setDay:1];
[comps setHour:0];
[comps setMinute:0];
[comps setSecond:0];

NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *startDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];

[cal release];  
[comps release];
```

Comment: Well, if you do so, it shows intent: that you want the time to be explicitly 00:00:00, rather than "the default." Semantics are slightly different.

Comment: I wouldn't bother, though, if the defaults are documented to be 0. (I haven't checked)

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"August 1st, 2005"];
```

Comment: @Fasid: I'm serious. The above call returns the date you've asked for.

Comment: Interesting. Auto complete didn't pick it up. I hope it's not a private API is it?

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to get a hard coded date and is totally legitimate.

Comment: warning: 'NSDate' may not respond to '+dateWithNaturalLanguageString:' but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Fasid: No, you're right. This method only exists on Mac OS, not on iOS. I'll remove this answer.

Comment: I love it when Apple has two different implementations of the same class, NSDate on Mac OS X responds to `dateWithNaturalLanguageString:`, on iOS though it does not (guess that means users can't type in dates on iOS). This means you will have to track through NSDateComponents, it's not really that bad though the class documentation has an example.

Comment: It's kinda-deprecated on Mac OS X too, as it doesn't really handle dates very well in languages other than English.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDateFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[myFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yy"];
NSDate *myDate = [myFormatter dateFromString:@"August/01/05"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on your timezone, but in GMT, the 1st of August 2005 at 1 minute past midnight was the UNIX timestamp 1122854401. So you can write...

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1122854401];
```

Comment: how did you calculate 1122854401

Answer (score 0):

[Introduction to Date and Time Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://web.archive.org/web/20100820034332/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html)

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:1];
[components setMonth:8];
[components setYear:2005];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```